# Is there a code to disable lazy loading of wordpress site logo?

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading

is there a code to disable lazy loading on just the site logo in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude that image from the plugin that you are using for lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

**You can disable Lazy Load on Specific Images by using the Hook Below**

Place the Hook in your functions.php file

```
    /* Disable lazy loading by image ID and size */
    function wphelp_no_lazy_load_id( $value, $image, $context ) {
    if ( 'the_content' === $context ) {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( 4532, 'large' ); // Change the ID and size
    if ( false !== strpos( $image, ' src="' . $image_url . '"' )) {
    return false;
    }

}
return $value;
}
add_filter( 'wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr', 'wphelp_no_lazy_load_id', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. A link to the documentation should be great.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr/

By the way, the documentation gives 2 params to this hook but your example gives 3.

Could you check-up ?